# Is there a way to add a variable to the variable table through the Admin menu

Tags: 7

Can I set a new key/value pair for the variable table from the Administrator `admin/config` menu in a Drupal 7 site? I don't want to have to create a one-time custom module that only contains a `variable_set()` function.

Comment: OR can I add it using the "INSERT" tab in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: You _could_ use PHPMyAdmin, to add the key/value pair, but you're better adding it to the `$conf[]` array in the `settings.php` file if you want to make it persistent, as suggested by @apaderno, or if you've got access to the command line and Drush, use @anonymous' solution. Both will help (but not guarantee) that the variable is cast correctly.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do it through PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your PHPMyAdmin installation, but mine won't allow me to insert the data into the `value` column in the `variable` table, as it's a `blob` column. The data in that column is serialized as you can see in the [implementation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x). As a result, adding it via the "Insert" tab is problematic. ***Instead***, I'll explain how you can add it in the "SQL" tab.

If you use an [online serializer site](http://php.fnlist.com/php/serialize), you can generate the proper data for the variable named `foo`

- if the `value` column is the string `bar`, it will give you `s:3:"bar";`
- if the `value` column is the array `['bar','baz']` it will give you

  ```
  a:2:{i:0;s:3:"bar";i:1;s:3:"baz";}
  ```

Then, use the "SQL" tab (instead of the "Insert" tab) and craft the appropriate insert statement.

If the value is a string:

```sql
INSERT INTO `variable`(`name`, `value`) VALUES ('foo','s:3:"bar";')
```

If the value is an array:

```sql
INSERT INTO `variable`(`name`, `value`)
VALUES ('foo','a:2:{i:0;s:3:"bar";i:1;s:3:"baz";}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
drush vset <variable-name> <variable-value>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override a persistent variable in the settings.php file. [default.settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/7.x) file contains example code for achieving that.

```php
// Change the site name to 'My Drupal site'.
$conf['site_name'] = 'My Drupal site';
```